# How to speed up Reflection Code?

Tags: java, performance, reflection

In my application, I use Apache's DBUtils class to read from a MySQL database.  I wrote a custom BasicRowProcessor that uses annotations on the data object's fields to read columns from the database.  It works really well code-wise, but the performance is rather slow when I'm pulling lots of rows.  For example, a 1500 row x 35 column result set will take 800ms with this code, but only 80ms if I'm using the standard JDBC code.

Question - what can I do to speed up this code? Specifically, I'm using a lot of reflection and annotations - are there tricks I'm missing to speed this up?

```
 @Override
   public <T> T toBean(ResultSet rs, Class<T> type) throws SQLException
   {
         T data = type.newInstance();

         Field[] f = type.getFields();

         for (int i=0; i<f.length; i++)
         {
            Field field = f[i];

            if (field.isAnnotationPresent(DBColumn.class))
            {
               String columnName = field.getAnnotation(DBColumn.class).name();
            }

            if (field.getType().getName().equals("int"))
            {
               field.setInt(data, rs.getInt(columnName));
            }
            else if (field.getType().getName().equals("long"))
            {
              field.setLong(data, rs.getLong(columnName));
            }
            // .... for all the other types

        }

    return data;
 }
```

Comment: If your code works, you should post to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: Tip one: Don't use reflection.

Comment: *Why* did you do this instead of using an existing JPA implementation?

Comment: @AntonH But it doesn't, it's too slow. And CR is rather dead (or unborn yet), you can't expect to get any answer there.

Comment: @maaartinus For me, too slow is a code that works, but not as fast as I want, which is, according to it's page, what CR is for. Also, if no one uses it, it'll never take off :)

Comment: @AntonH Too slow is often worse than broken. Broken code often needs a single line fix, inefficient code often needs a full rewrite. Simple example: "Review my bubble-sort, it's too slow". WTF. IMHO the only thing a CR take-off can achieve is to increase the confusion between the SO sites. Refusing working code here is ridiculous as half the code on CR is broken anyway. All that said, I partly agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps build & cache the row-mapping logic, so you don't have to scan the fields, annotations, result-set metadata & types every time.

JDBC metadata access is particularly slow.

In this example, you could provide a string 'key' to enable efficient caching of the mappers for different result-set types (differing column structures).

```
public BasicRowProcessor getReflectiveRowMapper (ResultSet rs, String resultSetKey, Class<T> type) {
    String key = resultSetKey+"-"+type;
    BasicRowProcessor result = rrmCache.get( key);
    if (result != null) {
        result = buildReflectiveRowMapper (rs, resultSetKey, type);
        rrmCache.put( key, result);
    }
    return result;
}

public BuiltRowProcessor buildReflectiveRowMapper (ResultSet rs, String resultSetKey, Class<T> type) {
}
```

Then..

```
public class BuiltRowProcessor extends BasicRowProcessor {
    protected FieldMapping[] mappings;

    @Override
    public <T> T toBean (ResultSet rs, Class<T> type) throws SQLException {
        T data = type.newInstance();
        for (FieldMapping field : mappings) {
            field.mapField( rs, data);
        }
        return data;
    }
}

abstract public class FieldMapping {
    protected Field field;
    protected int columnIndex;

    // constructor..

    abstract public void mapField (ResultSet rs, Object target) throws SQLException;

    protected void writeField (Object target, Object value) {
        try {
            field.setValue(target, value);   // or whatever API.
        } catch (Exception x) {
            throw new RuntimeException("error writing field: "+field, x);
        }
    }
}

public IntMapping extends FieldMapping {
    // constructor..

    public void mapField (ResultSet rs, Object target) throws SQLException {
        int value = rs.getInt(columnIndex);
        writeField( target, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't compare the names of the types. Compare the *types,* to int.class, long.class, etc.

In fact you don't need all those 'if' statements. Just call Field.set(), using ResultSet.getObject() as the argument. All the right things will happen internally. But I don't say this will be any faster.

You would be better off using the reflection facilities of the java.beans Introspector, as it caches all the reflective stuff for you.

Comment: Don't `Class` and `Method` do internal caching as well?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I guess so. And IIRC there are cases where own caching prevents some JIT optimization (I might be wrong).

Comment: Running some metrics on the functions, it doesn't matter if you compare the types to int.class or compare the type.getShortName() to "int".  Those are equally fast.  The real slow code is in the Annotation retrieval functions, isAnnotationPresent() and getAnnotation().  75% of the function time is in those 2 lines of code.